# How can I remove large amounts of particle effects from my server without logging in?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

My brother used `/particle` to put particles in my Minecraft server and they won't go away. I can't even get into my server because it lags so much.

Comment: Maybe a good idea could be to reduce your particle amount in the config. There's a button for particles, four types of amounts. *The last amount is no particles.*

Comment: Also, you can restart the server.

Comment: I have tried restarting the server, and I don't have a no particles, it only goes down to minimum particles.

Answer (score 1):

Prevent lag by doing the following, you can remove the large particle in there!

1. Change your particles to "Minimal"

[image]

2. Enter to your server
3. Try to remove the large particles that your brother did.
4. Done!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem may be in the number of particle you've set. If you had put like 100000 particle for each redstone signal plus relied this to a very fast redstone clock, your world will surely lag. I don't really know if this will work, but you can use McEdit, an editing program for Minecraft; if it's working, delete any part of the system. I hope this will help you.

Comment: There is no clock, he just activated it once and the particles won't go away, I've tried loading it in MCEdit and it crashes that too.

Answer (score 0):

Is your world important? The easiest solution here would be just to simply delete your world files and regenerate them.

Comment: This is a world on a server I am running for a large group of people, and most of them have pretty cool creations, so I don't think I could reset it.